# How to define a (string) array inside an object in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have the following statement in TypeScript:

```js
let foo = {
  bar: []
};

foo.bar.push("Hello World!");
```

However VSCode keeps complaining that this *isn't allowed*.

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)

So I try to define the type as follows:

```js
let foo = {
  bar: Array<string>
};
```

But then I get the message that the method push is not allowed:

> Property 'push' does not exist on type '{ (arrayLength: number): string[]; (...items: string[]): string[]; new (arrayLength: number): string[]; new (...items: string[]): string[]; isArray(arg: any): arg is any[]; readonly prototype: any[]; from(arrayLike: ArrayLike): T[]; from<T, U>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<...>, mapfn: (v: T, k: number) => U, thisArg?:...'.ts(2339)

Only way I found it to work was by defining it as follows:

```js
let arr : Array<string> = [];
let foo = {
  bar: arr
};
foo.bar.push('Hello World!')
```

Why can't I define the type inside the object itself? It seems cumbersome having to extract the types outside of it, into a variable.

Comment: You can always just `let foo: { bar: Array<string> } = { bar: [] }` no need to extract anything out. Just be explicit.

Comment: The `expression of type '"Hello World!"' can't be used to index type '(...items: never[]) => number'` error is because you used square brackets for the `push` function call

Comment: `foo.bar.push["Hello World!"]` is trying to look up the property `"Hello World!"` on the object `foo.bar.push`, not call the function `foo.bar.push` with the argument `"Hello World!"`.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Darn it, that was a typo whilst rewriting everything to simpler code. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```js
let foo = {
  bar: [] as string[]
};
```

You can also do it in a cleaner (imo) way by using a typed variable:

```js
interface Foo {
    bar: string[];
}

let foo: Foo = { bar: [] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a couple of choices:

You can define the type of `foo` inline:

```typescript
let foo: { bar: string[]; } = {
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    bar: [],
};

foo.bar.push("Hello World!");
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEDeEBGBDATogzmTAlgHYDmA2gLoDcEAvhALzIBQA9KxJ5wHq9-8CBzLmiyJKAGma0qzZrBgA6DJkUAHAK44AFgAoARAAkQwYDAgB1GJmAATAIT6AlFSA)

You might even extract that out into a reusable type:

```typescript
type Foo = { bar: string[]; }; // <=== (You could also use `interface`)
let foo: Foo = {
    bar: [],
};

foo.bar.push("Hello World!");
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvARgQwE4C4oDOw2AlgHYDmA2gLoDcUAvnQFAA2EwUAZgvvIhSoWUUVCx4otADQtmLFrzgA6CcrABXAgAsAFACIAEhDZtEAdTjY2AEwCE+gJR0gA)

Or you can use a type assertion on the blank array as [shown by JC97](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74273736/157247) (in general, type assertions are best avoided, but an assertion on an empty array is a reasonable exception):

```typescript
let foo = {
    bar: [] as string[],
};

foo.bar.push("Hello World!");
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jEF4IG8BQEMQEYEMBOAXBANoC6EOAzhJWHgJYB2A5mQDSoC+A3KqrDAB0uPIIAOAV0oALABQAiABIhgweAHUYeYABMAhPICU3IA)